# Java Datagram Socket don't receive packets

Tags: java, sockets, packet, datagram

I have this thread to receive data from a distant server as UDP packet. It did not enter in the IF clause.
This is my Thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    logger.info("Démarrage");

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(10234);
        while (true) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 2048);
            socket.receive(packet);
            Message message = new Message();
            if (message.parseData(packet.getData())) {
            messageUDP =message.message;
            logger.info(messageUDP);
            data.main(messageUDP);
            } else {
                logger.info("Could not parse message or message not related to Postfix");
                logger.info("Message was: {}", new String(packet.getData()));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("IOException:", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception:", e);
    }

    logger.debug("Arrêt");
}
```

I added `logger.info` everywhere to know were it gets blocked. I found that it gets blocked every time on `socket.receive(packet);`.

But I receive data on the port 10234, which I verified using a **tcpdump** command.

So I don't know what could be the problem here.

**Note: This code worked before, I didn't change anything since that, and today I receive nothing.**

Comment: also show the code which is sending packets

Comment: There is not really a code to send packet, because i redirect the logs of the server (rsyslog) on my Ip address and the port 10234.

Comment: Is the server(rsyslog) running?

Comment: Yes he is running, i used tcpdump and filtering on the port 10234, server 1 send data on this port, and server 2 where the thread is running, receive those data on the same port.

Comment: Has some nasty network tech. been fiddling with your network?  Adding routers, moving cables, blocking stuff?